# ExpressionEngine and Online Photo Service

Tags: file-uploads, ecommerce, ee, users, orders

I'm really sorry if I repeat somebody else's question but I could not really find any information on it for days. My deadlines are approaching and I am a little frustrated.

I am building a website for an online photo editing service. I never really thought about it before but I have to admit that I am actually stuck :(

The question is, if there is any ExpressionEngine Extension/Add-on that would suit me in order to provide this functionality (this is how it works):

A user selects a photo editing option [i.e. a shopping item] and adds it to their cart, then when they proceed to checkout they are offered to upload the photo that they would like to have edited [this is what I have no idea of how to implement], then they checkout via PayPal or any other method, I, therefore receive their order [that comes with the actually uploaded images/image links], then, when the photos are edited and I've received their payment, I mark the order as 'Complete' and they receive an invoice along with download links to their updated images OR they login to their account and access their updated images.

Could somebody who might have probably done something similar before give me a right direction? :(

So much appreciated, thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

The shopping Cart add-on Cartthrob can do this, and possibly the other e-commerce add-ons such as store or BrilliantRetail too (but i haven't checked). All you do on the checkout page is add a file upload field.

See this docs page that shows you can do that - http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/add_to_cart_form/

Everything else you have asked to do is simple enough in ExpressionEngine if you know the basics of how it all works.